# DOS Batch Array values needing spaces

Tags: batch-file

I'm very well and truely stuck on this. I need to have spaces in an array that I've set for a .bat file and then to run the following code. It doesn't work! Any ideas?

%2 is a variable parsed into this .bat file.

```
set App_Loc=("c$\Program Files\A B")
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%i in %App_Loc% do (
robocopy \\%2\%%i <USER DEFINED LOCATION>
)
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you call an array in this script. Basically, what exactly doesn't work? How do you expect it to work and how does it work actually?

Comment: have you tried placing quotes around the items that have spaces?

Comment: Don't confuse DOS with some command-interpreter in Windows. DOS is an OS.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that you want to take the files in c:\Program Files\A B and run a robocopy of them a server (defined in %2 - the second parameter to the batch script to a user defined location).

**I do believe that a lot of the misunderstanding can be alleviated if you spec your requirements. But this script should run giving you some output that can be debugged**

```
set App_Loc="c:\Program Files\A B"
for /f "tokens=*" %%f in ('dir /b %App_Loc%') do (
    robocopy "\\%2\%%~nf.%%~xf" "USER DEFINED LOCATION"
)
```

This is how I used it in a file called test.bat:

```
C:\temp>dir "c:\Program Files\A B" /b
ADONETArtifactGenerator_T4CodeGenTemplateCS.vstemplate
Barnaby Weir - Tarot Card Rock.mp3
DisableTaskOffload.reg

C:\temp>test.bat dummy server

C:\temp>set App_Loc="c:\Program Files\A B"

C:\temp>for /F "tokens=*" %f in ('dir /b "c:\Program Files\A B"') do ()

C:\temp>()
robocopy "\\server\ADONETArtifactGenerator_T4CodeGenTemplateCS..vstemplate" "USER DEFINED LOCATION"

C:\temp>()
robocopy "\\server\Barnaby Weir - Tarot Card Rock..mp3" "USER DEFINED LOCATION"

C:\temp>()
robocopy "\\server\DisableTaskOffload..reg" "USER DEFINED LOCATION"

C:\temp>
```